# How to change <p> tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, counter, shopping-cart

[screenshot of my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0qSQ.jpg)
So i have made a counter for a shoppingcart. Everytime you press on the + the counter goes up by one. But i also want the p tag to change when you press the +. As you can see in the screenshot, the price of the product is 159,95 euro so everytime i press the + the price of the product should go up by 159,95 euro.
here is my code:

```js
const allCounters = document.getElementsByClassName('qty');
let min = -1;
let result = document.getElementById('res');
let price = document.getElementById('prijs');

for (const someCounter of allCounters) {
  const minusBtn = someCounter.children[0];
  const counter = someCounter.children[1];
  const plusBtn = someCounter.children[2];
  minusBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (counter.value <= 0){
   console.log('disabled')
  }else {
   counter.value = parseInt(counter.value) - 1;
  }
  });
  plusBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter.value = parseInt(counter.value) + 1;
  });
}
```

```css
.qty{
  align-self: center;
}

.qty .count {
  color: var(--color-black);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 2px;
  min-width: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

.qty .plus {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: lightgrey;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font: 30px/1 Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.qty .minus {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: lightgray;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font: 30px/1 Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}

.minus:hover {
  color: var(--color-black);
}

.plus:hover {
  color: var(--color-black);
}

/*Prevent text selection*/
span {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

input {
  border: 0;
  width: 2%;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input:disabled {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
    <div class="qty">
        <span class="minus">-</span>
        <input class="count" type="number" name="qty" value="1" />
        <span class="plus">+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="prijs-product">
  <p id="prijs">€ 159,95</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm getting the initial item price by parsing the contents of `<p>` and then updating it every time the counter changes.

Note that this is a hackish way of getting the item price, there's got to be a way in your application to provide the client-side code with a numeric item price so there's no need to parse.

`formatPrice` function uses euro and comma as a separator, you might want to change it depending on selected currency/locale.

```js
const allCounters = document.getElementsByClassName('qty');
let min = -1;
let result = document.getElementById('res');
let price = document.getElementById('prijs');

const formatPrice = price => {
   return ('€ ' + price.toFixed(2)).replace('.', ',');
}

const priceNumeric = parseFloat(price.innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9.,]/g, "").replace(',', '.'));

for (const someCounter of allCounters) {
  const minusBtn = someCounter.children[0];
  const counter = someCounter.children[1];
  const plusBtn = someCounter.children[2];
  minusBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (counter.value <= 0){
   console.log('disabled')
  }else {
   counter.value = parseInt(counter.value) - 1;
  }
  price.innerHTML = formatPrice(counter.value * priceNumeric);
  });
  plusBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter.value = parseInt(counter.value) + 1;
    price.innerHTML = formatPrice(counter.value * priceNumeric);
  });
}
```

```css
.qty{
  align-self: center;
}

.qty .count {
  color: var(--color-black);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 2px;
  min-width: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

.qty .plus {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: lightgrey;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font: 30px/1 Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.qty .minus {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: lightgray;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font: 30px/1 Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}

.minus:hover {
  color: var(--color-black);
}

.plus:hover {
  color: var(--color-black);
}

/*Prevent text selection*/
span {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

input {
  border: 0;
  width: 2%;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input:disabled {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
    <div class="qty">
        <span class="minus">-</span>
        <input class="count" type="number" name="qty" value="1" />
        <span class="plus">+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="prijs-product">
  <p id="prijs">€ 159,95</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be better I mean, too work if you enter counter in the input. Hope I help you)

```js
const allCounters = document.getElementsByClassName('qty');
let min = -1;
let result = document.getElementById('res');
let price = document.getElementById('prijs');
const counter =  document.querySelector('.count')
const minusBtn = document.querySelector('.minus')
const plusBtn = document.querySelector('.plus')
  
for (const someCounter of allCounters) {
  minusBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (counter.value <= 0){
   console.log('disabled')
  }else {
   counter.value--
    refreshPrice(counter);
  }
  });
  plusBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter.value++
    refreshPrice(counter);
  });
  counter.addEventListener('change', () =>{
     refreshPrice(counter);
  });
}

function refreshPrice(curCounter){
price.textContent = '€ ' + (curCounter.value * 159.95).toFixed(2)
}
```

```css
.qty{
  align-self: center;
}

.qty .count {
  color: var(--color-black);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 2px;
  min-width: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

.qty .plus {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: lightgrey;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font: 30px/1 Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.qty .minus {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: lightgray;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font: 30px/1 Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}

.minus:hover {
  color: var(--color-black);
}

.plus:hover {
  color: var(--color-black);
}

/*Prevent text selection*/
span {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

input {
  border: 0;
  width: 2%;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input:disabled {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="qty">
        <span class="minus">-</span>
        <input class="count" type="number" name="qty" value="1" />
        <span class="plus">+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="prijs-product">
  <p id="prijs">€ 159,95</p>
 </div>
```